# Upload a file to AWS S3 pre-signed URL using Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload a file to Amazon's S3 using a pre-signed URL.  I get the URL from a server which generates the URL & sends it to me as part of a JSON object.  I get the URL as a String, something like this:

https://com-example-mysite.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/userFolder/ImageName?X-Amz-Security-Token=xxfooxx%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2Fxxbarxx%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=xxAlgoxx&X-Amz-Date=20170831T090152Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Credential=xxcredxx&X-Amz-Signature=xxsignxx

Unfortunately, when I pass this to Retrofit2, it modifies the String attempting to make it into a URL. I've set `encoding=true` which took care of most of the problem but not completely. I know the String works as it is.  I've tried it in Postman & get a successful response.

1st I tried just putting the String (except for what I cut out as baseUrl) as a whole into the Path

```
public interface UpdateImageInterface {
    @PUT("{url}")
    Call<Void> updateImage(@Path(value="url", encoded=true) String url, Body RequestBody image);
}
```

The calling code:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://com-example-mysite.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/userFolder/")
            .build();

    UpdateImageInterface imageInterface = retrofit.create(UpdateImageInterface.class);
    // imageUrl is "ImageName..."
    Call<Void> call = imageInterface.updateImage(imageUrl, requestFile);
```

This works mostly except the the '?' (after "ImageName") get converted to "%3F".  This causes a Bad Request / 400.

My next attempt was to create a query with Retrofit2 but then dump the whole String (with multiple queries) into the query.

```
public interface UpdateImageInterface {
    @PUT("ImageName")
    Call<Void> updateProfilePhoto(@Query(value="X-Amz-Security-Token", encoded = true) String token, @Body RequestBody image);
}
```

The calling code:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://com-example-mysite.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/userFolder/")
            .build();

    UpdateImageInterface imageInterface = retrofit.create(UpdateImageInterface.class);
    // imageUrl is "xxfooxx..."
    Call<Void> call = imageInterface.updateImage(imageUrl, requestFile);
```

This gets the '?' rendered correctly but all of the '&' get changed to "%26"

Lastly I tried passing the whole String in `baseUrl()` but that gives an IllegalArgumentException for not having '/' on the end.

I know that I could parse the pre-signed URL to make multiple queries & assemble them in Retrofit2 as queries should be done but I'd like to avoid that processing.

To restate the question:

Is there a way to easily (without heavy String parsing) upload a file to S3 with a pre-signed URL using Retrofit2?

Comment: The library, or something it depends on, seems a little bit broken.  Take a look at the comments, here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1199... note the last one, in particular.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With help from a colleague, this is the solution.

```
public interface UpdateImageInterface {
    @PUT
    Call<Void> updateImage(@Url String url, @Body RequestBody image);
}
```

Calling code:

```
    String CONTENT_IMAGE = "image/jpeg";

    File file = new File(localPhotoPath);    // create new file on device
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(CONTENT_IMAGE), file);

    /* since the pre-signed URL from S3 contains a host, this dummy URL will
     * be replaced completely by the pre-signed URL.  (I'm using baseURl(String) here
     * but see baseUrl(okhttp3.HttpUrl) in Javadoc for how base URLs are handled
     */
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://www.dummy.com/")
        .build();

    UpdateImageInterface imageInterface = retrofit.create(UpdateImageInterface.class);
    // imageUrl is the String as received from AWS S3
    Call<Void> call = imageInterface.updateImage(imageUrl, requestFile);
```

[Javadoc](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/) for info on `@Url` (class Url) & 
`baseUrl()` (class Retrofit.Builder)

`MediaType` is a class in the [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library that is often used with Retrofit (both from Square).  Info about constants passed to the parse method can be found in the Javadoc.

Comment: Hey, I am facing a similar problem. How are you generating the requestFile here?

Comment: @AmitBarjatya Edited answer to include declaration of requestFile.

Comment: @Gary99, what is CONTENT_IMAGE?

Comment: @Eric See updated answer.  Added definition of CONTENT_IMAGE & info about it's source.

Comment: What about the status of a big image >8MB. Will it work?

Comment: @Nithinjith I don't know. My files were much smaller and I'm not working with that code now so I can't test it.

Comment: @Gary99 The presigned is a form, how did you include the rest of it in this request? I can see you only included the file.

Comment: @ofcourse_swift It's been 2 years since I've done this.  I can't say I remember many specifics.  I do know that what I have here worked for me though.

Comment: I m getting 403 , when tring to upload a video file.. any thoughts?

Comment: 403, in this case occurs, due to the problem of the structure of the uploading file.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162161/put-upload-file-to-aws-s3-presigned-url-retrofit2-android/74140811#74140811

Answer (score 1):

Use the following while uploading directly to S3 using presigned URL.

```
@Multipart
@PUT
@Headers("x-amz-acl:public-read")
Call<Void> uploadFile(@Url String url, @Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Part MultipartBody.Part part);
```

Comment: A note on this solution `@Headers("x-amz-acl:public-read")` should only be added with caution as it may lead to a signature mismatch.