# AWS S3 file upload with retrofit2 video/image corrupt

Tags: android, amazon-s3, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

When uploading files to s3 using retrofit uploads successfully and returns a 200 however the file is corrupted. The file can be either a video or image.

```
 val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), file)
 val body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(mediaType, task.file_name, requestFile)

assetService.uploadAsset(contentType, task.upload_url, body)
```

where contentType is either "video/mp4" or "image/jpeg" and mediaType is either "video" or "image"

the service :

```
@Multipart
@PUT
fun uploadAsset(
    @Header(CONTENT_TYPE) contentType: String,
    @Url uploadUrl: String,
    @Part file: MultipartBody.Part
): Single<ResponseBody>
```

The files upload and look correct however they are corrupt and cannot be viewed.

I've checked this question but still stuck. [AWS S3 Rest API with Android Retrofit V2 library, uploaded image is damaged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32663281/aws-s3-rest-api-with-android-retrofit-v2-library-uploaded-image-is-damaged)

Comment: Why don't you use s3 SDK for uploading? The documentation is pretty clear about how to do it and much better than rest.

Comment: we're using a presigned url for the upload similar to this question and so retrofit seemed fitting: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991720/upload-a-file-to-aws-s3-pre-signed-url-using-retrofit2

Comment: Are you saying that each time u are uploading to different buckets according to your api response?

Comment: different upload urls for each asset. The URLs are correct and i get a 200 response from the call however when i go to view the videos/images on S3 they are corrupt. The error must be within the requestbody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removed Multipart upload and it worked.

Comment: Why we need to remove multipart from retrofit API call?.S3 will do it automatically?

Comment: The urls our api was generating for S3 could not handle multipart upload and so by removing this and uploading as a Body it worked perfectly

Comment: Hi I am facing the exact same issue? Did your removed multipart from ApiInterface?

Comment: @DhruvKaushal yes I removed multipart and all worked fine. Our upload urls did not support multipart uploading to AWS. Hope it works for you!

Comment: Still I have error I don't use multipart .

Answer (score 0):

as an improvement and elaboration on @nt95's answer, you are using the multipart to send the file to the server, while it seems unnecessary to do so, just create a `RequestBody` out of the desired file and send it as a `@Body` in parameters.

**not working code:**

```
@Multipart
@PUT
fun uploadAsset(
@Header(CONTENT_TYPE) contentType: String,
@Url uploadUrl: String,
@Part file: MultipartBody.Part
): Single<ResponseBody>
```

**working code:**

```
val requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(contentType), file)
```

and pass it to the interface as follows:

```
@PUT
fun uploadAsset(
@Header(CONTENT_TYPE) contentType: String,
@Url uploadUrl: String,
@Body file: RequestBody
): Single<ResponseBody>
```

and you will be fine